# How can i use xsl:if for this result?

Tags: xslt

How can i use xsl:if for output type=label. I don't how can I make if statement syntax.

I'm use xslt 1.0.

```
<xsl:if test="">                                 
 <xsl:attribute name="type">                                     
   <xsl:value-of select=""/>                                     
 </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:if>
```

this is resource :

```
<xxxxx type="str">label</xxxxx>
```

I like to output like this

```
<key name="xxxxx" type="label"/>
```

Comment: I think you need `<xsl:if test="@type='str'">`. Also note your `xsl:value-of` needs to be `<xsl:value-of select="." />"`

Comment: It's work!, Thank you.

Comment: I've added this as an answer, along with a some more helpful information, hopefully. Thanks!

Comment: When using XSLT it is rarely necessary to use any XSLT conditional instructions at all -- when using the full power of the language these can (and should) be avoided -- as shown below.

Answer (score 0):

The expression you want is this, assuming you are matching the `xxxxx` element

```
<xsl:if test="@type='str'">
```

Note that, I don't know what the rest of your XSLT looks like, or if you were looking for something generic, but you might want to learn about [Attribute Value Templates](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#attribute-value-templates) if you were creating or changing other attributes. For example...

```
<xsl:template match="*">
  <key name="{local-name()}">
    <xsl:if test="@type='str'">                                 
      <xsl:attribute name="type">                                     
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>                                     
      </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>
  </key>
</xsl:template>
```

When applied to this XSLT

```
<xxxxx type="str">label</xxxxx>
```

The following is output

```
<key name="xxxxx" type="label"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can i use xsl:if for output type=label. I don't how can I make if
>   statement syntax.
>
> I'm use xslt 1.0.

**When using XSLT it is rarely necessary to use any XSLT conditional instructions at all** -- when using the full power of the language these can (and should) be avoided.

Here is one such solution to the problem:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="xxxxx[@type='str']">
    <key name="xxxxx" type="{.}"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When this transformation is applied on the following XML document (none provided!):

```
<t>
    <a/>
    <xxxxx type="str">label</xxxxx>
    <b/>
    <c/>
</t>
```

the wanted, correct result is produced:

```
<key name="xxxxx" type="label"/>
```